# Отсортировать список списков по алфавитному порядку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, список

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Дан список [['k', 'b'], ['d', 'a']].
Нужно отсортировать его по алфавитному порядку по второму члену подсписка. То есть, должно получиться при выводе['d', 'a'] а потом ['k', b].

Comment: Массив наверное всё-таки не такой и заполнен не переменными, а строковыми данными? В чём сложность?

Comment: добавил скриншот входных значений

Comment: Почему бы не добавить текстом сам массив входных данных  в виде объектов питона? То что на скриншоте не похоже на список из списков и непонятно содержимое.

Comment: The Sound of Silence; Simon & Garfunkel Space Oddity\n
A Night at the Opera; Queen\n
A Night at the Opera
Space Oddity; David Bowie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l = [['abc', 'cba'], ['cba', 'abc'], ['aab', 'bba']]
l.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])

# [['cba', 'abc'], ['aab', 'bba'], ['abc', 'cba']]
```